# jquery-ajax-c# success function is executed but no response

Tags: c#, jquery

The post is fired and I can see the below in firebug

```
POST http://localhost:1148/WebSite2/frmMain.aspx/webDelete 200 OK 15ms
```

**jQuery code is:**

```
$.ajax({
   url: "frmMain.aspx/webDelete",
   type: "POST",  
   dataType: "text",
   contentType:"text/plain",
   data: {id:"abc"},
   success: function(data){alert("success");alert(data)},
   error: function(){alert("failed");}
});
```

Then two alerts in the success function are fired but the second alert is empty

**Server side coding:**

```
[WebMethod][ScriptMethod]
public static string webDelete(string id)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

    return id;
}
```

---

currently trying without the involvements of param, the error function is triggeres, no success

**jquery code**

```
$.ajax({

        url: "frmMain.aspx/webDelete",
        type: "POST",  
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        async: true,            
        success: function(data){alert("success");alert(data.d) },
        error: function(){alert("failed"); }

    } );
```

**server code**

```
[WebMethod][ScriptMethod]
public static string webDelete()
{
   return "hello";
}
```

**firebug info:**

**Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control   private
Connection          Close
Content-Length  11732
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date            Thu, 18 Jul 2013 09:47:34 GMT
Server          ASP.NET Development Server/8.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept          application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length  2
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Host            localhost:1148
Referer         http://localhost:1148/WebSite2/frmMain.aspx
User-Agent          Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help ^_^

Was able to find an answer through this wonderful post!

[jquery ajax with asp.net not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750339/jquery-ajax-with-asp-net-not-working)

Note: This isuue was caused by the .NET version problem

Answer (score 0):

In order to see what's wrong.

1. Debug `webDelete()` to see that id is actually 'abc'!
   might be problem in parsing the form data...
2. check the actual response using **FireBug** or **Chrome F12**

---

Try navigating to :

```
http://localhost:1148/WebSite2/frmMain.aspx/webDelete?id=myNeetID
```

- does this fire up the WebMethod?
- does this return myNeetID or a blank?

notice: you might need to Enable GET method.

Comment: 1. that code is not getting executed 2. The actual response is the html code of the client page 3. How do I add new line to this comment!?

Comment: Nothing happens, I don't see any ajax post in firebug, so no request, no response, the page just loads if I hit that url.

Comment: @rps its just for testing propose. some configs disallow GET requests. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819267

Answer (score 0):

If you use [WebMethod][ScriptMethod] in combination, you need to make some changes to your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "frmMain.aspx/webDelete",
   type: "POST",  
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: JSON.stringify({id:"abc"}),
   success: function(data){alert("success");alert(data.d)},
   error: function(){alert("failed");}
});
```

See:

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: I will let you know after giving that a try, but why JSON? coz the 'ScriptMethod' tells the server method that the request is fired through script? At First I didn't include that ('ScriptMethod') and it didn't work at that time too.

Comment: The control goes to error function; changed **$.toJSON** to **JSON.stringify** coz got the error “ $.toJSON is not a function ”, I had also removed the content-type from server side. The alert for "failed" got fired

Comment: Ah OK. Sorry for the toJSON() that is not part of the standard JQuery. Removing the data type from server side is also OK. Could you debug the communication with Firebug? That will give us a better idea of whats going on with the request.

Comment: `http://localhost:1148/WebSite2/frmMain.aspx/webDelete` that is the request link in the firebug, I suppose it is missing the parameter? `data: {id:"abc"}` this is how I have given the param in JQuery code and at the post view in the firebug I see **Source ---
id=abc**

Comment: The data should be part of the POST message. You don't see any parameter as part of the URL because you are executing POST. Source should be sent as JSON. Not as a key/value collection as usually

Comment: Try modifying the data to this.  data: '{"id":"abc"}' and see if this works. Estrange that stringify is not behaving as it should.

Comment: I know the param shouldn't be visible in the browser url for POST, what I mean was shouldnt it be visible in the firebug? I guess not.I tried putting single quotes , no use. one other thing I noticed **Content-Type text/html; ** for response and like before it is still returning the entire page's html code

Comment: Thank you for the help, It was a .NET version problem and the issue is resolved now