# ASP.NET jQuery error: Unknown Web Method and Unable debug aspx web form app with visual studio 2019

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

i have this simple ajax call from client-side :
this is in the TestPage.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Services" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Piece Of Cake </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/navigation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/form.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/validateForm.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/effects.js"></script>
    <script>  
        $(document).ready(function () {          
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "TestPage/GetName/",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("success")
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("failure")
                },
                error: ErrorOccur
            });
        });
        function ErrorOccur(data, status, req) {
            alert("error:"+req.responseText + " " + status);
        }
 </script>
</head>
```

now in the TestPage.aspx.cs file i have :

```
namespace Foo.html
{
     
    public partial class TestPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var t = 0;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetName()
        {
            var chk = new check
            {
                subject = "hello! ",
                description = "13 Years Old"
            };
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chk);
        }
        public class check
        {
            public string subject { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I can debug the cs files like the "RouteConfig.cs" in the app.
but looks like i have a problem debugging the web forms part.
When i try to debug the app after setting breakpoints in the GetName and Page_Load methods the debugger never reaches them. the app running but l keep getting the ajax error that says:

```
error:undefined parsererror
```

im using the IIS express ( which comes with VS )
all debug are set in web.config :

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
```

why i can't debug the app?
why it never reaches GetName method?

**UPDATE**
I changed the javascript error callback and now im getting the error:

```
unknown web method GetName
```

Comment: is this page using Master Pages? i.e. has a `MasterPageFile` attribute?

Comment: dont think so all i see in the header is  :
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>  
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Services" %>

Answer (score 0):

A simple example with `.NET Framework 4.7.2`, the ASPX page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterLess.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForms_DDL_Selection.MasterLess" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var name = 'kipi';

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '<%= ResolveUrl("MasterLess.aspx/GetName") %>',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{'name': '" + name + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code behind CS:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
        
[WebMethod]
public static string GetName(string name)
{
    return "Hey there " + name;
}
```

In case there's a 401 error this needs to be modified in `~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs` (or the line commented out):

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

Comment: Thanks but still not working i try to add :
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestPage.aspx.cs"%>
but i got this error after build:
1>C:\Dev\my\\project\Myproject\html\TestPage.aspx.designer.cs(12,23,12,24): error CS1001: Identifier expected

Comment: @user63898 edit the question and add the aspx code

Comment: done the edit , you can see the header of the aspx page

Comment: is this a WebForms project? With ASPX pages? where are the `AutoEventWireup` `CodeBehind` and `Inherits` attributes on the `@Page` directive?

Comment: this is legacy code that i got , there was none there

Comment: what Webforms version? what .NET framework version?

Comment: <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />

<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>

Comment: @user63898 try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11768760/4000335

Comment: this port is from 2012 , not sure it is valid now ...

Comment: @user63898 that question specified the same `parseerror` as in this question, the assumption with those attributes missing from the page directive is that this is a legacy WebForms 2.0 app and it's missing those extensions from the answer.

Comment: i don't think its a legacy webform app this is from the csproj file :
<HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.WebForms.5.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.ScriptManager.WebForms.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">

Comment: is it perhaps a website project? does this project have a global.asax file in the root?

Comment: it could be the project was upgraded from a legacy WebForms 2.0 project that's still missing those extensions to enable ajax, further troubleshooting steps would be comparing the dll's that are present in the project bin folder and so on but that's already going into a more complex scenario, i.e. comparing the dll's with a fresh new WinForms project created in VS2019 with the latest .NET Framework